# Reloading Prototype in Unity doesn't decrease ammo & bullets correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reload

So I'm a new programmer in C# (shocker, I know) an I've tried to prototype a realoding system in Unity, but just with sound and meters in Unity.

The problem is that when I reload it doesn't decrease the ammo correctly. Because I made it so that when reloading when you still have bullets left, it will just subtract the Ammo from the shots, I already had to implement that it will just subtract one if (shots == 0)

After I while I ran into some problems (another shocker) and saw that my whole programm was just if() statements. After rewriting and refactoring I still had my problems and if statements. I was told to not post 200 lines of code and be specific.

I'm gonna post 200 Lines of code 'cause I don't know any better. I'm so sorry.

public class Shot : MonoBehaviour 
{

```
//"CoolDown" is used to limit rate of fire of my gun
public int CoolDown = 5;

//used to prevent shooting while realoding
public int ReloadCoolDown;
public bool IsReloading = false;

//obvious
public int Shots = 0;
public int TotalShots;
public int Magazine = 25;
public int Ammo = 125;
public bool NoAmmo = false;



void Start() 
{
    ReloadCoolDown = 150;
}

void Update()
{
    //Checks if ammo is still present
    CheckForAmmo();
    //just so i could test some stuff faster, can be ignored
    Skip();
    //Also checks for ammo
    if(!NoAmmo)
    {
        GameShot();
        ReloadEmpty();
        ReloadHalf();
        if (IsReloading == true)
        {
            ReloadCoolDown--;
        }
        if (CoolDown <= 0)
        {
            CoolDown = 0;
        }
        CoolDown--;
    }
    else if (NoAmmo)
    {
        ExecNoAmo();
    }
}

//Just getting the audio clips from unity
AudioSource GetAudio(int index)
{
   AudioSource[] audio = GetComponents<AudioSource>();
    if (index == 1)
    {
        return audio[0];
    }
    else if (index == 2)
    {
        return audio[1];
    }
    else if (index == 3)
    {
        return audio[2];
    }
    else if (index == 4)
    {
        return audio[3];
    }
    else
        return null;


}

void GameShot()
{
    //Shoots, increases total shots and shots (for that mag), plays audio, sets the cooldown for the next shot, decreases bullets in mag
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) &&
        CoolDown <= 0 && IsReloading == false)
    {
        TotalShots++;
        GetAudio(1).Play();
        CoolDown = 5;
        Shots++;
        Magazine--;
    }
}

//Reloads if every bullet in the magazine has been fired
void ReloadEmpty()
{
    //this and ReloadHalf() is where you can find so many if statements and where most of my code is tangled up...
    //im trying to check for ammo and if the mag is completely empty to trigger the empty reload
    if (Magazine == 0 && Ammo > 0)
    {

        if(Ammo >= 25)
        {
            Magazine = 25;
        }
        else
        {
            Magazine = Ammo; 
        }

        Ammo -= Shots;
        Shots = 0;
        ReloadCoolDown = 130;
        GetAudio(2).Play();

        IsReloading = true;
    }
    if (ReloadCoolDown <= 0)
    {
        ReloadCoolDown = 150;
        IsReloading = false;
    }
}
void ReloadHalf()
{
    //Again, many if statements and entaglement...
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && Magazine < 26) && Ammo > 0)
    {
        if (Shots == 0)
            Ammo -= 1;
        ReloadCoolDown = 80;
        GetAudio(3).Play();
        if(Ammo >= 25)
        { 
            Magazine = 26;
            Ammo -= Shots;
        }
        else if (Ammo <= 25)
        {
            Magazine += Ammo;
            if(Magazine > 26)
            {
                int i = Magazine - 25;
                Ammo = i;
                Magazine = 26;
            }

        }
        Shots = 0;
        IsReloading = true;
    }
    if (ReloadCoolDown <= 0)
    {
        ReloadCoolDown = 100;
        IsReloading = false;
    }
}

void ExecNoAmo()
{
    //plays no ammo sound if ammo == 0
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        GetAudio(4).Play();

}

void CheckForAmmo()
{
    if (Ammo <= 0 && Magazine <= 0)
        NoAmmo = true;
}

void Skip()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        Ammo = 25;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is no clear question here. All you have stated is that you are having problems.

Comment: I recommend taking this to [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. One thing I see in `GetAudio()` is that the index passed is always 1 higher than the index used.  `return audio[index-1];` would work, collapsing *all* of those if-blocks into a single statement (you would still need to check for out-of-bounds, though).

Comment: what problem are you hoping we can help solve?

Comment: @Draco18s My problem is that that code doesn't correctly count the shots when reloading when you are on low ammo. Sorry, I should'ce stated that more clearly. Also my problem wasn't the GetAudio() Method. It were the Reload Methods. I can't post my code on Code Review SE because my code doesn't work. I'm new to this side so I wasn't quite sure how to ask my question. I'll be more specific next time. Reweriting my code now. :D

Comment: Edit your question to include a problem statement (outside your code block! No one is going to notice the comments until they start looking for the problem stated).

Answer (score 1):

Your counter bullets method is so rarely.I leave here my method in case it usefull someone

(Example of values)

```
    bulletsTotal = 30;
    bulletsMagazine = 15;
    bulletsMagazineSize = 15;
```

On Update Method

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            if(bulletsMagazine!= 15)
            {   
                if (bulletsTotal > 0)
                {
                    asGun.clip = reload;
                    asGun.Play();
                    Reloadgun();
                } 
            }
        }
```

And this the funcion of reload

```
public void Reloadgun()
    {
        int bulletToReload= bulletsMagazineSize-bulletsMagazine;

        if(bulletToReload< bulletsTotal)
        {
            bulletsTotal = bulletsTotal - bulletToReload;
            bulletsMagazine = bulletsMagazine + bulletToReload;
        }
        else
        {
            bulletsMagazine = bulletsMagazine + bulletsTotal;
            bulletsTotal = 0;

        }

        bulletsTxt.text = "M92\n   " + (bulletsMagazine) + "/" + bulletsTotal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried refactor your code and the problem is that you trying to do too many things, you should separate the concern and split it into several classes.

I created new class PlayerSounds which contains method the play the sounds in your code, but I was lazy to refactor it fully so the logic of your code is still together in one class, though it should be split into 3 classes, one managing shooting, one managing reloading and one for your ammo and magazine. Also I was utterly confused of the logic for reloading so I completely changed, it will be up to you fit your need.

Things I did: Removed magic numbers to some degree, they were changed to constants. Removed fields NoAmmo, IsReloading, Shots. Removed all comments, any methods and fields should be self explanatory. Reversed negative conditions - they are harder to read.

I also completely changed logic for reloading, I felt like you were overthinking it, some if statements would be always false so I removed them, I also changed the numbers 25 and 26 to constant and I didn't understand why you need to substract ammo based on number of Shots, when all you have to do is just fill the magazine, so I simplified it. Change it to fit your need.
After you look at the code you might even realise that both reloading methods are almost identical and could be made into one, eliminating if statement and play sound based on number of bullets you reloaded.

To get rid of ifs is to keep methods do what you intended, if your method has too many ifs it is probably doing a lot of thing, so just split it and name the methods in a way it's easy to understand what they are doing.

```
class PlayerSounds
    {
        private const int PlayerShootingSound = 0;
        private const int PlayerReloadingMagazineSound = 1;
        private const int PlayerReloadingHalfOfMagazineSound = 2;
        private const int PlayerHasNoAmmoSound = 3;
        private AudioSource[] audio;

        public PlayerSounds(AudioSource[] audio)
        {
            if (audio == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(audio));

            this.audio = audio;
        }

        public void PlayerShot()
        {
            audio[PlayerShootingSound].Play();
        }

        public void PlayerReloadingMagazine()
        {
            audio[PlayerReloadingMagazineSound].Play();
        }

        public void PlayerRealodingHalfMagazine()
        {
            audio[PlayerReloadingHalfOfMagazineSound].Play();
        }

        public void PlayerHasNoAmmo()
        {
            audio[PlayerHasNoAmmoSound].Play();
        }
    }
```

And your Shot class:

```
public class Shot : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int MagazineSize = 25; // to remove magic number 25 and 26, also to give this number a meaning
    private PlayerSounds playerSounds;

    public int CoolDown = 5;
    public int ReloadCoolDown;
    public int Shots = 0;
    public int TotalShots;
    public int Magazine = 25;
    public int Ammo = 125;

    void Start()
    {
        ReloadCoolDown = 150;
        playerSounds = new PlayerSounds(GetComponents<AudioSource>());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (playerTryingToFire())
        {
            tryToShoot();
            playNoAmmoSoundWhenWithoutAmmo();
        }
        else if (playerTryingToReload())
        {
            tryToReloadHalfMagazine();
            playNoAmmoSoundWhenWithoutAmmo();
        }

        tryToReloadEntireMagazine();

        if (CoolDown > 0) CoolDown--;
        if (ReloadCoolDown > 0) ReloadCoolDown--;
    }

    bool playerTryingToFire()
    {
        return Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
    }

    bool playerTryingToReload()
    {
        return Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R);
    }

    void tryToShoot()
    {
        if (playerCanFire())
        {
            TotalShots++;
            playerSounds.PlayerShot();
            CoolDown = 5;
            Magazine--;
        }
    }

    bool playerCanFire()
    {
        return CoolDown == 0 && ReloadCoolDown == 0 && Magazine > 0;
    }

    void playNoAmmoSoundWhenWithoutAmmo()
    {
        if (!hasAmmo())
        {
            playerSounds.PlayerHasNoAmmo();
        }
    }

    void tryToReloadHalfMagazine()
    {
        if (magazineIsNotFull() && hasAmmo())
        {
            int missingBulletCountInMagazine = MagazineSize - Magazine;
            transferAmmoToMagazine(missingBulletCountInMagazine);
            ReloadCoolDown = 80;
            playerSounds.PlayerRealodingHalfMagazine();
        }
    }

    private bool magazineIsNotFull()
    {
        return Magazine < MagazineSize;
    }

    void tryToReloadEntireMagazine()
    {
        if (Magazine == 0 && hasAmmo())
        {
            transferAmmoToMagazine(MagazineSize);
            ReloadCoolDown = 130;
            playerSounds.PlayerReloadingMagazine();
        }
    }

    private void transferAmmoToMagazine(int maximumAmountToFitMagazine)
    {
        int possibleBulletCountToFit = Math.Min(Ammo, maximumAmountToFitMagazine);
        Magazine += possibleBulletCountToFit;
        Ammo -= possibleBulletCountToFit;
    }

    bool hasAmmo()
    {
        return Ammo > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for.. I was so tangled up in Code and I was getting confused of it myself.. thank you very much for this.

Comment: Okay after some testing I'm having trouble getting the sound to work... your initial code spits out an error on my end. "the function nameof-Operator isn't available in C# 4."

Comment: Sorry, nameof is C# 6 feature, all it does is change the name of your field/property/whatever to string, so just change nameof(audio) to "audio" and it should work.

Comment: Okay.. it took me some time now almost everything works. I had to combine our two scripts because your logic was what I needed but the sound didn't work and Unity had some issues with the classes. Now everything is in one class and it's working just right. Thank you very much :)